# Using combinations in python for very large sequences

Tags: python, memory, combinations

I'm trying to determine all the combinations of 87 different strings that could make up a 29 element sequence. I was using combinations in python to do this and it works fine if the sequence is only 4 elements long but it can't handle 29. This is the code I'm using:

```
combos = itertools.combinations(testv, 29)

usable_combos = []
for i in combos:
    usable_combos.append(i)
```

but the code fails at the loop stage. I assume this is some kind of memory issue but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sure, you are adding everything into a list, and at some point you are adding more than your memory can handle. Why are you doing that? Why not process the combinations *as you loop*?

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to stuff a **huge number of tuples** into a list here. [101.416.867.967.028.166.758.360 different tuples](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Binomial%5B87%2C+29%5D), to be precise. A number so big I don't even know how to spell it out, but you can start with [101 and almost a half sextillion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers) as an approximation.

When you made combinations of 4 elements, there were just [2.225.895 different combinations](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Binomial%5B87%2C+4%5D) (a little over 2 million), something that is quite manageable, but you pushed it to levels that most computers simply cannot store in memory all at once.

Rather than add everything to a list, then use that list, you'd be better off processing those combinations *as you loop*:

```
for i in combos:
     # process i, move on
```

or find a different approach to solving your problem, one that doesn't involve looping over all those possible combinations. Perhaps there are ways to reduce the number of combinations you actually need to consider?

As an aside, rather than use a `for` loop and `list.append()`, you could have just used:

```
combos = itertools.combinations(testv, 4)
usable_combos = list(combos)
```

to create your list.